# res.send doesn't print to console

Tags: ajax, node.js

I have an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "http://localhost:3000/",
dataType: "json",
data: JSON.stringify({"start" : a.rangeInfos[0].startMarkerId,
         "end" : a.rangeInfos[0].endMarkerId}),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function(result) {
console.log(result);
  }
  });
```

that is being handled on the server like:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
res.send('Got a POST request');
database.doSomething(req);
});
```

doSomething is defined in the connection.js, as:

```
doSomething : function(req) {
console.log(req.body);
db.collection('ranges').insert(req.body) 
}
```

Everything works great except that the result is not being printed out.
It did print out before I made some changes to the connection and server files, so I'm suspecting it's not a front-end issue, but some weird async issue that keeps escaping me.

Would appreciate help.

Comment: what is `result` for you? you have several `console.log`, which one is not being printed?

Comment: res.send('Got a POST request') is not printed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ajax you declared

> dataType: "json"

that means you're expecting data back from the server under json format. So the string `Got a POST request && saved To DB` cannot be parsed

Answer (score 0):

first res.send must be the "last thing", so change "doSomething" to something like that:

```
doSomething : function(req, callback) {
    db.collection('ranges').insert(req, function(err, result){
        if(err) return callback(err);
          console.log(req.body);
          console.log('result ', result[0]._id);
        return callback(null, result[0]._id);
    })
}
```

And

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    database.doSomething(req, function(err, result){
         res.send('Got a POST request && saved To DB');
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't _have_ to be the last thing. OP's code will send a response, then do a DB transaction. It won't just stop in the middle of the `/` handler.

Comment: yes you have right ^^, but imagine if we have an Ajax request and we expect to see what happen (success OR failure), that's why i suggest to leave res.send at the end for example, if he got an error on DB insertion, he can use res.send with a custom error, but in the example above he can't, because the response is already delivered

Answer (score 0):

You've not included any body parsers. `req.body` is `undefined` unless something has actually parsed it. From the [manual](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)

> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer.

Pull in `body-parser`, and use it as middleware, e.g.

```
var bodyparser = require("body-parser");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use("/", bodyparser.json());

// ... and the rest of your routes.
```

Comment: I stringify my data and sent it to the server using the AJAX post. I then take the obj and continue to pass it to the DB and store it. I'm using MongoDB and can successfully see the object stored in my DB the way I'd like. Not sure if I need to parse it then.
Also, it looks like the whole process works so why doesn't the server return 'Got post request'?

Answer (score 0):

I've made the proper changes suggested above (because it's good coding), but the problem was with the way I was sending the result back to the client. I guess the parser was parsing out an empty string, so I changed the post route to be:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
database.doSomething(req, function(err,result){
   res.send({result:"Got a POST request"});
});

});
```

then the console.log on the client worked as expected.